# New Xcode target: changing configuration settings / preprocessor macros

Tags: iphone, xcode

I just followed some tutorials on creating a new target for a lite version, and everything is working well. One thing I'm worried about is it's mentioned that you need to set configuration to all configurations and am just wondering where to do this in Xcode 4.6 (or do you need to do it anymore)? I'm clicking my target, then build settings, and am not seeing the option that used to be there in the older versions of Xcode.

Also, I've added "LITE_VERSION" to preprocessor macros in build settings and it works fine, but I've seen mentioned in other places that it should be `-DLite_VERSION`. Does it matter?

The tutorial I was reading was [here](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2098).

It says to make sure "The configuration dropdown in the info panel is set to “All Configurations”. I've seen this in other tutorials as well, even where one guy said he submitted to the app store without this being set and ads were being shown in his paid version.

Comment: Please provide some reference to the tutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `.xcconfig` files to set the preprocessor flags, there are two options.

1) Using `OTHER_CFLAGS` you need `-D` in front of each definition

```
OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -DLITE_VERSION
```

The list is passed as given to the compiler. It corresponds to "Other C Flags" in Xcode build settings.

2) Using `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` there is no `-D`

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) LITE_VERSION
```

The list is passed through `-D` flag to the compiler. It corresponds to "Preprocessor Macros" in Xcode build settings.

Both are the same for your purposes.

Answering your real question (hard to discern as the title and the body ask different things),  in Xcode 4 there is a small triangle on the left of every build setting. It allows you to set a value for all configurations (when the triangle is pointing right) or for each configuration individually (when the triangle points down). If you use `.xcconfig` files you can associate different configuration files to each build configuration in the Project > Info > Configurations panel.

Comment: Thanks, would you happen to know about the configuration setting?

Comment: Updated the question to have a link to the tutorial with the statement in question.

Answer (score 2):

In `Target` -> `build settings` -> in the first line you can filter "Basic" or "All", maybe the setting you are looking for is just filtert off.

You can name your preprocessor macros whatever you want, as long as you use the exact definition in your code, like... `#ifdef LITE_VERSION`